# Why does the Countdown stuck at "1"?

Tags: javascript, timer, counter, setinterval, countdown

```
var count=6
var counter=setInterval(timer, 1000);

function timer(){
count=count-1;
if (count === 0){
     requestAnimationFrame(repeat);
     clearInterval(counter);
     return;
}
var countdown = createEntity($('<div id="countd"><p id="countp"></p></div>'));
game.add(countdown);
document.getElementById("countp").innerHTML=count;
}
```

This is my approach to the Countdown. I'm coding a Game. First of all it shows a Countdown... But why does it stuck at "1"? And if I'm playing it still staying "1" over the display.

My idea was, **clearInterval(Counter)** but it doesn't work. Are there any other approches?

Comment: First you decrement the variable, then you test if it is zero. If it is zero, you return from the loop. If it wasn't zero, you update the div tag. In other words: if the counter is zero you don't update the div-tag.

Comment: @some Posting that comment as an answer seems to be good idea.

Comment: Side note:
"count = count - 1;"
can be shortened to a more readable:
"count--;" Also, the code might be more easy to understand if converted to a FOR loop.

Comment: How can I delete the <div> when count = 0?

Comment: ```if (count === 0) {$('#coundid').remove();}```

Comment: @TedNyberg Douglas Crockford disagrees with you that post-decrementation is more readable… I use it in loops, but otherwise I usually use `count -= 1`. Using a for-loop would not help in this case, since each iteration of the loop should happen one second apart.

Comment: Hehe, I said it "might" make it more readable. :D Personal preference, I guess. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you:

1. decrement the variable
2. test if it is zero and if so you return from the loop.
3. In all other cases you update the div tag.

***In other words: if the counter is zero you do not update the div-tag, and therefor the last displayed value is 1***

Assuming that the problem you are describing is the only problem with your code, you could change it to something like this:

```
function timer() {
  var countdown = createEntity($('<div id="countd"><p id="countp"></p></div>'));
  game.add(countdown);
  count -= 1;
  document.getElementById("countp").innerHTML=count;
  if (count === 0) {
    requestAnimationFrame(repeat);
    clearInterval(counter);
  }
}
```

I basically just moved the if-statement to after the field is updated. I have not tested the code, but if you get the idea of what to change.

I am however curious if you really want to call `createEntity` and `game.add(countdown)` on every timer-invocation. In most cases you want to create the tag before you call the timer-function, and just update the value. But maybe you are doing some animation and therefor need individual tags for each value, so it isn't necessarily wrong to do it that way.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a display only issue (which I am guessing it is), then the update to HTML should be made before you return from the function when the count is 0. In case the counter goes to 0, you are not updating the display.

```
if (count === 0){
    //assuming repeat is a variable defined somewhere in the rest of your code
    requestAnimationFrame(repeat);
    document.getElementById("countp").innerHTML=count;
    clearInterval(counter);
    return;
}
```

Comment: this code not works, because has some exception, e.g. ```repeat``` variable is not defined

Comment: I am assuming that in the original code (the one that has not been posted in the question) will have repeat (and all other variables like game etc.) defined. Have added the same assumption in the answer.